# How to get video as response from youtube-dl?

Tags: node.js, youtube-dl, node-telegram-bot-api

I am writing a telegram bot to download a video from YouTube, I use the youtube-dl api, and when I try to get a video as response, but the video simply downloads to the root directory, but the  script doesnt send it to the user, it gives me an error.

Error type:

```
Test video sending
[youtube] En8go1kP3rg: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: DJ SMASH feat Po�t -  (REMIX 2020) TOP Xit-En8go1kP3rg.mp4
[download] 100% of 7.47MiB in 00:01
(node:10996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: output is not defined
    at TelegramBot.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\index.js:29:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10996) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

There is my code:

```
const telegramApi = require("node-telegram-bot-api");
const token = "myApi";
const fs = require("fs");
const youtubedl = require("youtube-dl-exec");

const bot = new telegramApi(token, { polling: true });


const start = () => {
  bot.on("message", async (msg) => {
    const text = msg.text;
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    const mode = "youtube";

    if (text === "/start") {
      await bot.sendSticker(
        chatId,
        "https://tlgrm.ru/_/stickers/b50/063/b5006369-8faa-44d7-9f02-1ca97d82cd49/1.webp"
      );
      await bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Пошла жара...");
    }
    if (mode === "youtube") {
      console.log("Test video sending");
      const video = await youtubedl(text, {
        noWarnings: true,
        preferFreeFormats: true,
      }).then((output) => console.log(output));
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, output);
    }
  });
};

start();
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Ignore the mode variable, this is in case I want to add other services besides youtube.

UPD.:
If i write
bot.sendMessage(chatId, output)

It gives a response in telegram:

```
[youtube] 7rlRet5t5pU: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: miyagi &  -  (slowed + reverb)-7rlRet5t5pU.mp4
[download]   0.0% of 8.63MiB at 139.74KiB/s ETA 01:03[download]   0.0% of 8.63MiB at 367.33KiB/s ETA 00:24[download]   0.1% of 8.63MiB at 857.10KiB/s ETA 00:10[download]   0.2% of 8.63MiB at  1.79MiB/s ETA 00:04 [download]   0.4% of 8.63MiB at  1.90MiB/s ETA 00:04 [download]   0.7% of 8.63MiB at  2.15MiB/s ETA 00:03 [download]   1.4% of 8.63MiB at  3.14MiB/s ETA 00:02 [download]   2.9% of 8.63MiB at  4.31MiB/s ETA 00:01 [download]   5.8% of 8.63MiB at  5.62MiB/s ETA 00:01 [download]  11.6% of 8.63MiB at  7.51MiB/s ETA 00:01 [download]  23.2% of 8.63MiB at  9.09MiB/s ETA 00:00 [download]  46.3% of 8.63MiB at 10.05MiB/s ETA 00:00 [download]  92.6% of 8.63MiB at 10.44MiB/s ETA 00:00 [download] 100.0% of 8.63MiB at 10.55MiB/s ETA 00:00 [download] 100% of 8.63MiB in 00:01
```

If i write:
bot.sendVideo(chatId, output)

Error in terminal:

```
Test video sending
[youtube] 7rlRet5t5pU: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: miyagi &  -  (slowed + reverb)-7rlRet5t5pU.mp4
[download] 100% of 8.63MiB in 00:00
Unhandled rejection Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: invalid file HTTP URL specified: Wrong URL host
    at C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src\telegram.js:291:15
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\MR.ROBOT\Desktop\TM-Bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use `sendVideo` method? It support mp4 file format - see more here https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/release/doc/api.md#TelegramBot+sendVideo

Also, the `output` variable is undefined casue it is in different scope. You should put `bot.sendX` call in the callback where you have a `console.log` funciton, so:

```
}).then((output) => {
 console.log(output)
 bot.sendMessage(chatId, output); // or sendVideo
});
```

Comment: A edited my question with your solution, it doesnt work

Comment: @JOKER Did you check what's acutally in that `output` variable and if it is suitable to be passed to `sendVideo`? Also you should check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await will help you in the long run.

Comment: I looked in the youtube-dl-exec documentation, there is no information, I think this api is not suitable for a bot. I'll look for another api.